# Laravel Nova / Difference between solo and pro package

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5, laravel-nova

What is the difference between the Solo and Pro licenses?

I can see that the Pro has **For Businesses & Teams** as a feature.

Does that mean in the Solo version you can only login as a Nova admin with 1 user only?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in the [Laravel Nova](https://nova.laravel.com/) site:

[image: Laravel Noval Pricing - January 2019]

The only difference is that, acording to their license system, if you or your company makes less than 20k, you should buy the "SOLO" license. Otherwise, go for the "PRO" one.

And no, there isn't any limitation about how many "admin" users you can have. All of this settings are done by you when implementing this package.

Notice that the pricing is per-site based. Also, with the "PRO" team, you have dedicated support, the standard in this kind of services.

---

Disclaimer: I have zero affiliation with the Laravel/Nova team.

Comment: Thanks for the response!